# Svelte: <svelte:window bind:innerHeight /> is not working with style attribute in div on window resize

Tags: javascript, resize, window, height, svelte

On window resize, I have tried to add dynamic height as style property in div element, using svelte special element `<svelte:window bind:innerHeight />` but I am not getting the proper result which I am looking for, Is there anything I missed.

**Code**:-

```
<script>
    var innerHeight;
</script>

<svelte:window bind:innerHeight={innerHeight} />

<div style="height: {innerHeight};">
    <h1>window height : {innerHeight}</h1>
</div>
```

**Output**:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0JQZ.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have got the answer since the innerHeight is unit less value we have to add px like this style="height: {innerHeight}px;"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`innerHeight` is a unit less value, in order to use it as you do, you have to add the unit yourself to the style tag'

`style="height: {innerHeight}px;"`

(note the extra *px*)

Comment: Yes, I got the solution and its working fine. Thanks a lot!!